# How use barcode reader on web page?

Tags: asp.net, usb, barcode-scanner

I have an ASP.NET web app wherein I'm wanting to allow users to plug in a USB barcode reader and use.  I.e. instead of typing a long number, to scan it and have the value automatically populate in a field on a page.  Anybody know how i would go about doing this?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

When barcode reader is attached to computer and user scans something, barcode reader will send this scanned barcode text to any:

```
<input type='text'/>
```

which is currently active, and will end this text with "Enter" automatically.

So you can just attach to your javascript input event listener, which checks, if key is pressed and key code is 13 (Enter or Return), and on this event populate your grid or send data to server.

After it - just clear your current  input field and wait for new data from barcode reader.

This is pure browser-oriented solution, while there might be others.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an API for integrating and communicating with Point-Of-Service (POS) peripheral devices that is called [Microsoft Point of Service for .NET v1.12 (POS for .NET)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5355).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just working with the same scenario. My final solution was kind of a hack. Basically using the `OnTextChanged` event of a `TextBox` (and `AutoPostback="true"`), but first setting an initial value (`Text` property), so when you scan a code, the event will trigger (assuming that the scanner make a `Return` after rendering the number).

I used this approach because I don't want to use javascript.

Hope it helps.